# CSS animate div from bottom from its height

Tags: html, css, transform

I am trying to achieve the following, animate text div from the bottom for its full height. I can do this with javascript when I can get its height for transformY. Is there a way to do this with pure css?

(note, transformY is currently hardcoded for showcase).

```js
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.inner').css({"transform": "translateY(73px)"});
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}

.inner {
     position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transform: translate(0, 100px);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="trigger">
  show it
</button>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `top:100%` to initially hide the text since percentage value within top consider the height of the container. Then use `transformY(-100%)` to show it since percentage inside transform consider the height of the transformed element:

```js
/*$('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.inner').css({
    "transform": "translateY(-100%)"
  });
});*/
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  position:relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
.wrap:hover .inner{
 transform:translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="trigger">
  show it
</button>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor<br>Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I stop it going to far above if there is more text than fits?

Comment: @Toniq you mean if there more text than the container height?

Comment: Yes, in this case can it stop at the top maybe?

Comment: @Toniq yes, simply use `top:0`

Comment: Where would I place this?

Comment: @Toniq I meant to replace `transform:translateY(-100%);` by `top:0` as I don't think you can have both behavior together, so you can probably test the height of the content. If it's lower use transform, if it's bigger than the container use top